# Error during expanding macro command in preamble

Tags: macros, preamble

I try to create a command if...else which seems correct when i expand it in body but not in preamble. The package answers seems to be not include because the \Newassociation command is unknown. I try to use \ifodd directly and it works but il would understand my error (quoting, escaping, ... ?).

**Log of pdflatex**

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
               {
l.14 ...tionfiles]{answers}}{\usepackage{answers}}

(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/answers/answers.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/verbatim.sty))

! Undefined control sequence.
l.29 \Newassociation
                {SOL}{Solution}{tempo}
```

**LaTeX code**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}

\newlength{\personnelmm}
\setlength{\personnelmm}{1pt}

\newcommand{\ifpersonnel}[2]
{\ifodd\personnelmm{#1}\else{#2}\fi}

\ifpersonnel{\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}}{\usepackage{answers}}

% \ifodd\personnelmm
% \usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}
% \typeout{THEN}
% \else
% \typeout{ELSE}
% \usepackage{answers}
% \fi

\Newassociation{SOL}{Solution}{tempo}
\renewcommand{\Solutionlabel}[1]{\textbf{Solution #1}}

\begin{document}
...
```

Comment: Personnelmm is a length not a number so running if odd on it makes no sense. Use a counter or explain what you are trying to do. If it is just an on/off switch use an if construction or use a toggle construction from etoolbox

Comment: note that after  `\setlength{\personnelmm}{1pt}` then `\ifodd\personnelmm` is false as it will be cast to `sp` by multiplying by 2^{16}, and whether it is true or false you are using `\usepackage` inside a local `{}` group so most of the definitions made by the package will be discarded.

Comment: For boolean checks/conditionals I like to use `etoolbox` and its `toggle`s. But you could also use `expl3` and its vast array of conditionals and programming tools. Those solution offer a slightly more LaTeX-y syntax and are more natural than using lengths for a true/false switch.

Comment: `\setlength{\personnelmm}{1sp}` would work; but why not just doing `\newcommand{\personnelmm}{1}`?

Answer (score 4):

After

```
\newlength{\personnelmm}
\setlength{\personnelmm}{1pt}
```

then `\personnelmm` will be 65536sp and so act as 65536 (even) in a numeric context.

However you do not want a length here at all, simply use

```
\newif\ifpersonnelmm
\personnelmmtrue % or false
```

Then your definition is doing either `{#1}` or `{#2}` so either way the package is being loaded inside a local group and so all the definitions are being discarded.

The intended definition is

```
\newcommand{\ifpersonnel}[2]
{\ifpersonnelmm #1\else #2\fi}
```

However it would be good practice not to name it starting `\if...` and reserve such names for commands defined via `\newif`  otherwise it is hard to check `\if...\else...\fi` nesting by eye. (That is it confuses humans, it doesn't confuse the system).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help
the new version follows and works !

```
\newif\ifpersonnel
\personneltrue % or \personnelfalse
\newcommand{\sipersonnel}[2]
{\ifpersonnel #1\else #2\fi}

\sipersonnel{\usepackage[nosolutionfiles]{answers}}{\usepackage{answers}}
```